# Create Generic List<Type> from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, list, generics

In one of my classes I have the following property:

```
public List<ClassP> MyPlanes { get; set; }
```

In another method I have a the `propertyInfo` of the property above (the function self does not know where the propertyinfo comes from). Right now i'm trying to `create a list of classP` when i only have the propertyInfo of `MyPlanes`. So far my attempts seem to be in vain, this is howfar i got sofar:

*variable prop is the PropertyInfo of MyPlanes*

```
public void GenerateList(PropertyInfo prop)
{
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0)
            { 
                List<prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First()> myValueList = 
                    new List<prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First()>();
            }
}
```

The creating of the list (with the code above) gives the following error `Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Note:** I want the list creating in a syntax (or a syntax similar) as visible above. I want to keep my code as generic as possible

Comment: Note: I would call `prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()` only once and cache the result. I believe it is an expensive operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a generic class when you have the type, you can't use the brackets `<>` because you don't know the type at compile time. You need to do something like this:

```
var baseType = typeof(List<>);
var genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First());
```

Now you have the correct type and you can create it like so:

```
IList myList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Edit: although as Selman22 says above, you already have the `PropertyType`, so you don't need to get the generic type unless you are trying to make a different generic class with the same generic argument (say you have a `List<T>` and need to make a `Dictionary<Type,T>` or something). So I'll leave my answer in case you encounter that situation.

Comment: Is there any way to extract (in my case) `List<ClassP>` without actually mentionning `ClassP` in the definition then? If so do I retain all the functionalities of the `List` (i'm mainly interessted in the `Àdd()` function)

Comment: Made small change to your code to represent my working code. Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: @Knorriemans: Whoops, sorry, I rolled it back before I saw your comment. I (*think*) restored it.

Comment: A good restore :) . Now i can create generic list (iList in this case that i later on set my property to) as i was desiring!

Comment: @Knorriemans: Just note that while you can use `Add`, it's not going to be type safe. If you pass the wrong type of object to `Add`, you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: The check on the `Add` was already present. As there is always a check when setting the property :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunutely, it does not work like that.You need to use `Reflection` to create a new instance as well:

```
var list = (List<ClassP>)Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
```

`CreateInstance` method returns `object`. If you don't know the type at compile time, there is no way to cast it. Best thing you can to would be using `dynamic`.And that way you can access any members without any compile time error, but clearly it's not safe.

You should probably reconsider whether you *really* need to use `Reflection` here.If your problem can be solved without using `Reflection` then you should go with that way.

Comment: Let me say, reflection is desirable not obligatory.  But i feared that my goal would be hard to achieve. I'll look into that `dynamic` type. Perhaps I could enhance my class to prevent those compile errors.

Comment: Building on that idea, you could use prop.SetValue to set the property to the new list you created i.e.             `public void InitPropertyValue(PropertyInfo prop, object instance)
            {
                prop.SetValue(instance, Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType));
            }` where instance is an instance of the type that has the MyPlanes property